# Printing PHP string using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string

I got a script which uses an array that was created in PHP and was encoded to JSON. It then take the string and use it to set a value for an element I created:

```
var val ="";
if(arr != null)
{
 if((arr[i] != undefined) && (arr[i]["value"] != undefined))
 {
     var val = JSON.stringify(arr[i]["value"]);
     val.replace(/"/g , "");
 } 
}
cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='"+val+"' style='padding-right: 0px;'/>";
```

The problem is that every string on the screen appears with the "" around the string itself. for example "5". I want it to be just 5 and not "5". I thought the replace I did to the val was supposed to do it but it didn't work. why is that?

Comment: show your json value please?

Comment: don't use `JSON.stringify` , just use `arr[i]["value"]`

Comment: @charlietfl if I don't use stringify then what is printed are the words Object.object or something like that

Comment: Please show more detail then. If value is number or string it won't print `Object`. Perhaps you need to check `typeof` first A demo would help

Comment: So what other info do you need me to add?

Comment: Create a demo using some sample data in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem is just something I keep forgetting all the time.

The line `val.replace(/"/g , "");` is missing its magic and should be:

```
val = val.replace(/"/g , "");
```

I'm leaving the question so other people might be able to see how to decode a JSON string and how to use an array which was created in PHP.

Comment: That sounds like a workaround, rather than having addressed the actual issue. Quotes don’t magically appear out of nowhere.

Comment: I believe they appear because of the JSON encoding was it not?

Comment: No, the quotes in JSON are part of the _syntax_, not the _data_. If after decoding JSON you have quotes that you do not want, then you must have put them in there somewhere in the first place.